# XSLT: For each node transform, if A =2 and A=1 were both found do this else do that

Tags: xslt

Example 1:

```
<time>
   <timestamp>01:00</timestamp>
   <event>arrived<event>
</time>
<time>
   <timestamp>02:00</timestamp>
   <event>left<event>
</time>
```

Example 2:

```
<time>
   <timestamp>02:00</timestamp>
   <event>left<event>
</time>
```

The XSLT needs to do:

- FOR EACH  node DO:
- IF event=arrived THEN set eventtype=atdestination
- IF event=left is found AND event=arrived is found THEN set new node type=leftdestination ELSE set type=left

XSLT applied to example 1:

```
<event>
   <time>01:00</time>
   <type>atdestination</type>
<event>
<event>
   <time>02:00</time>
   <type>leftdestination</type>
<event>
```

XSLT applied to example 2:

```
<event>
   <time>02:00</time>
   <type>left</type>
<event>
```

Comment: Can you explain a=1 and a=2?  Perhaps the structure of your transformations?  Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: You are not able to clearly formulate a problem... :(

THere is no "A" anywhere in the text -- only in the title and this is absolutely confusing.

This only shows that your only problem is you don't know what the problem is.

It is typically the case that people who cannot express a problem succintly, usually don't have a good idea themselves what the problem is. Thereore, do not waste the time of SO readers if you have not at least a satisfactory definition of the problem.

F A I L  !

Comment: okay, I'm guilt of being incoherent.  but I do know what my problem is.  the above description does outline what I need.  I'm looping thru a source file, and if case one exists then do A else do B.  Problem is if XSLT was procedural, I could use a variable to set/reset its value (true/false).  But it is functional, and a variable in XSLT is not what I am use to, so I need to find a different solution.  

Also, I admit, my title is not correct with description.  I was trying to be generic.  

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="time">
  <event>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </event>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="timestamp">
  <time><xsl:value-of select="." /></time>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
  <type>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".='arrived'">
        <xsl:text>atdestination</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=".='left' and ../../event[type='arrived']">
        <xsl:text>leftdestination</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=".='left' and not(../../event[type='arrived'])">
        <xsl:text>left</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>undefined</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </type>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Tomalak, could you, please explain what you think this person wants? It lacks any meaning.

Comment: @Dimitre: As far as I have understood it, the resulting `<type>` should be either `"atdestination"` (when only `time[event='arrived']` exists), `"atdestination"`/`"leftdestination"` (when both `time[event='arrived']` and `time[event='left']` exist) or `"leftdestination"` (when only `time[event='left']` exists).

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, your answer worked for me.  It took awhile to get back to this problem, but I just implemented it and it works.  

evidently you understood my problem clearly.  thanks again!